# .Net Plugin Architecture Not Working with Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, plugins, nuget

I have a .Net Core 3.1 console application that loads plugins.  One of my plugins connects to Sqlite and so it has a Nuget dependency on Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.  However, I'm getting a missing DLL exception from the console app when loading/running the plugin because the following path doesn't exist:

`MyConsoleApp\bin\x86\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\win-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll`

I also have an MsTest project which tests this Sqlite plugin project.  It does not have the same problem.  Apparently the `runtimes` folder and contents will automatically exist if a Visual Studio project (1) is some kind of executable and (2) has a pertinent Nuget or project reference.

Following those rules, two of my three Visual Studio projects do not have the runtimes folder:

- The plugin has a Nuget dependency on Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, but does not have the `runtimes` folder because the plugin project is a DLL...not an executable.
- The MsTest project which tests the Sqlite plugin **does** have the `runtimes` folder and contents because (1) it it is a type of executable and (2) it has a project reference to the plugin project (which in turn references the Nuget package).
- The main console app is an executable, but (intentionally) doesn't have a project reference to the plugin.  Thus it does not have the `runtimes` folder.

How do I solve this?  As a hack I have simply copied the missing DLL into the output target directory for the console app.

Also, if I add a project reference from the console app to the plugin, this problem is solved.  But, as stated, I don't want the console app to have project references to any plugins.  Plugins should be discovered dynamically.  I think fixing this may have something to do with creating a nuspec file.  However, [the documentation for nuspec files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks) has no commentary about addressing this.

Comment: What is your plugins project type and how does your console app use the plugins?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> .Net Plugin Architecture Not Working with Nuget

**Just as you said that**, the **lib plugins** project which references `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` does not have the runtime folder and when an `exe` project reference the **lib plugins** project, the `runtimes` folder will be copied into the the exe project's output folder.

**Solution**

**1) Since** you do not want to reference the **lib plugins** project for the console project, you can just do a [copy task in msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019) from the **MsTest** project's runtimes folder.

Write this target in the `xxx.csproj` file of `Net Core 3.1` console application:

```
<Target Name="Copy_Runtimes" AfterTargets="Build">

        <ItemGroup>
            <CopyItems Include="..\MsTest\bin\Debug\xxx\runtimes\**\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(CopyItems)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)runtimes\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"></Copy>
</Target>
```

**2) Besides**, you can also install the nuget package called [sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite/3.13.0?_src=template) in the `net core 3.1` console application, and this package only contains the `runtimes` folder and does not include other com dlls for using.

It is actually a pure service package for providing `runtimes` folder.

You can install this package in your console project directly and if you are not satisfied with this, you can only try **solution 1** to solve the issue.

Comment: I've encountered two problems with this answer.  The first is that I need to have an additional `*` glob to grab all `*Connector` projects `Include="..\*Connector\bin\Debug\xxx\runtimes\**\*.*"`.  That extra asterisk prevents the %(RecursiveDir) from working correctly.  The second problem is that I've found copying binaries to be *highly* unreliable when dealing with .Net Core in general or plugins in particular.  I've since learned that I need `dotnet publish` to ensure that all references are properly transmitted.